# $x^2+3x+24$ is a perfect square then find the value of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find all integer values of $x$ where $x^2+3x+24$ is a perfect square. By guessing I found one solution that $x=5$.I found the problem in the exercise of a book in the chapter of polynomials. So please help me.

Comment: Hint: complete the square.  Second hint: to avoid getting fractions, use the fact that if $x^2+3x+24$ is a square then so is $4(x^2+3x+24)$.

Comment: More generally there's also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876246/perfect-square-of-the-form-n2anb/1876277#1876277) question (and probably some others; that's just the one I personally remember answering).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^2+3x+24 = n^2$
so
$x^2+3x+9/4 = n^2-24+9/4$
or
$(x+3/2)^2 =n^2-87/4$
or
$(2x+3)^2 =4n^2-87$.

Therefore
$87
=4n^2-(2x+3)^2
=(2n-2x-3)(2n+2x+3)
$.

$87=3*29$,
so it can be factored as
$87
=1*87,3*29
$.

Therefore
$(2n-2x-3,2n+2x+3)
=(-87, -1), (-29, -3), (3, 29), (1, 87)
$.

If
$(2n-2x-3,2n+2x+3)
=(a, b)
$,
then
$4x+6 = b-a$
and
$4n=b+a$
so
$x = (b-a-6)/4$
and
$n = (b+a)/4$.

For these 4 sets,
$x = (-87+1-6)/4
=-92/4 = -23
$,
$x = (-29+3-6)/4
=-32/4 = -8
$,
$x = (29-3-6)/4
=20/4 = 5
$,
$x = (87-1-6)/4
=80/4 = 20
$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the giving term is larger than (x+1)^2 and is smaller than (x+5)^2, then it must equal to the square of (x+2) or (x+3) or (x+4), plug these 3 terms into the equation and you will get the answer.

Comment: This is good advice for more general problems of this type such as high-degree "nearly square" polynomials, where exact factorization isn't possible but you can still reduce to a finite set of cases.

Answer (score 1):

Dario Alpern has a nice [calculator](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) that will show you a step-by-step derivation of the four solutions, which are $x = -23,-8,5,20.$ You should input $a = 1, c = -1, d = 3, f = 24$ in the left frame.